# Execute stored procedure on multiple linked servers vs separate connections

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I have to get some data from multiple databases using stored procedures. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2014. 
I could have each stored procedure on his own server, or all procedures on a single server with linked servers to the rest of databases.

I am wondering on the pros and cons for each method in the terms on performance, as the returned data on a daily basis use will be around 2000 rows, but it could reach at a maximum ~30000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is that each stored procedure execute on his own server. Even you will call all procs from one server with linked server.

When you call a procedure that contains a linked server the data is load before the processes begin. But you call a procedure through the linked server the proc will process on the own server before answer you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!